# Split is not available?

Tags: debian, split

I've just tried to run a simple shell script on my Readynas server running Debian, and it appears that the `split` command is not available.

This is a server which I can't fiddle too much with, so if there's a way to get `split` running without risk of breaking other native ReadyNAS features, I would be super happy.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`split` is a standard utility, included in the [`coreutils`](http://packages.debian.org/coreutils) package. This package has the priority “required” (and is marked “essential”), so a normal Debian installation would have it.

I guess your server is running [BusyBox](http://busybox.net/) utilities. BusyBox is a suite of utilities designed for systems with little disk space or little memory. Many of its features are optional, and Debian's normal BusyBox package doesn't include the `split` utility (presumably because it isn't used often).

You can emulate some uses of `split` with the `head` utility and a bit of shell programming. Here's a quick and dirty script to split the input into fixed-sized chunks:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
i=1000000001          # Below we'll strip away the leading 1; this is
                      # a trick to have leading zeroes in the file names.
prefix=$1             # The files will be called ${prefix}000000001, etc.
chunk_size=$2         # in bytes, or 42k or 42m for kB and MB respectively
while
  head -q -c "$chunk_size" >"$prefix${i#1}"
  [ -s "$prefix${i#1}" ]   # Stop when we make an empty chunk.
do
  i=$((i+1))
done
rm "$prefix${i#1}"         # Remove the last, zero-sized chunk.
```

Store that script as `simple_split`. Usage example:

```
tar -cf - /big/dir | simple_split foo.tar- 1m
```

This command creates 1MB-sized files called `foo.tar-000000001`, `foo.tar-000000002`, etc. You can assemble them with `cat`; note that thanks to the fixed-width format of the numbers, the files are ordered in lexical order of their names.

```
cat foo.tar-????????? | tar -tf -
```

Comment: Hi Giles. Thanks a lot for your answer - it clears up a lot of questions. How would I use your suggested snippet? Put it in a shell script and call it like I would call split? I.e `tar .... | mysplit `?

Comment: @Industrial Test it (I typed this directly in my browser), adapt it a bit, and then yes, feed it input on its standard input.

Comment: Hi Giles. Please bear with me  -I am far from good at this. I put the snippet as a file in `/bin` and tried piping tar to it, but it creates two files, one zero-byte and one file containing a list of the files in the tarball, which stays the original size.

Comment: @Industrial I've updated my script a bit and added a usage example.

Comment: A bit? That's fantastic! :) Thanks a lot Giles